# Polymorphism in member fields, when the fields are collections of objects which are also a part of an inheritance tree

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm having trouble articulating the question so I'll start with an example:

```
public class BirdCollector
{
    protected Dictionary<string, Bird> nameToBird_;

    public BirdCollector(Dictionary<string, Bird> nameToBird)
    {
        nameToBird_ = nameToBird;
    }
}

public class ExoticBirdCollector
{
    public ExoticBirdCollector(Dictionary<string, Bird> nameToBird)
    : base(nameToBird)
    { }

    public ExoticBird GetExoticBird(string name)
    {
        Bird bird;
        if(nameToBird_.TryGetValue(name, out bird))
        {
            return (ExoticBird)bird;
        }
        else
        {
            // handle error
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The dictionary I'm passing into the `ExoticBirdCollector` contains all `ExoticBird`, which extends `Bird`, but I am having to re-cast them every time in `GetExoticBird()`.

Is it possible to cast these once, maybe in the constructor, so that everytime I get a bird from nameToBird_ it will be an `ExoticBird`?  The compiler doesn't have any way of knowing that I'm passing all `ExoticBirds` in the map, so is there a way to enforce this other than declaring a separate dictionary e.g. `Dictionary<string, ExoticBird> nameToExoticBird_`?

What I'm considering doing now (which seems incorrect) is making nameToBird_ in `BirdCollector` private instead of protected, and hiding it in `ExoticBirdCollector` a dictionary of string and `ExoticBird`.

My original question was answered, but I have a related follow-up. If I were to require the `Dictionary<string, ExoticBird>` to be passed into a new class which accepts `Dictionary<string, Bird>` in the constructor, how could I achieve that?  I suspect the down-cast can't be made because the objects are inside a container.  I could create a new `Dictionary<string, Bird>` and loop through the `Dictionary<string, ExoticBird>` to fill it and then pass it, but this seems like a hack.

Comment: Does `ExoticBird` inherit from `Bird` ?

Comment: Yes, I will edit to mention that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your base class generic and move the `GetBird` method

```
public class BirdCollector<T> where T : Bird
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, T> nameToBird_;

    public BirdCollector(Dictionary<string, T> nameToBird)
    {
        nameToBird_ = nameToBird;
    }

    public T GetBird(string name)
    {
        T bird;

        if (nameToBird_.TryGetValue(name, out bird))
        {
            return bird;
        }

        // handle error
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can declare its derived class like this

```
public class ExoticBirdCollector : BirdCollector<ExoticBird>
{
    public ExoticBirdCollector(Dictionary<string, ExoticBird> nameToBird)
        : base(nameToBird)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both.  This fixes my main issue of not being able to pass the Dictionary<string ExoticBird> into the constructor.  I also like the generic GetBird method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics and type constraints:

```
public class Bird
{  }

public class ExoticBird : Bird
{  }

public class BirdCollector<T> where T : Bird
{
    protected Dictionary<string, T> nameToBird_;

    public BirdCollector(Dictionary<string, T> nameToBird)
    {
        nameToBird_ = nameToBird;
    }
}

public class ExoticBirdCollector : BirdCollector<ExoticBird>
{
    public ExoticBirdCollector(Dictionary<string, ExoticBird> nameToBird)
        : base(nameToBird)
    { }

    public ExoticBird GetExoticBird(string name)
    {
        ExoticBird bird;
        if (nameToBird_.TryGetValue(name, out bird))
        {
            return bird;
        }
        else
        {
            // handle error
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```